# Query inside Search function in Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

when an income or expense is added two entries are done to a table called TabGLEntry (two entries with most similar values except debit , credit, both have same voucher no). I want to display Values of TabGLEntry (Only one value for each voucher no should be displayed). so this is my sql query for this scenario

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tabGLEntry` 
GROUP BY  `voucher_no`
```

when i tried this on my db it worked as intended. Now to implement it in Yii2
i tried this query in Search Model (TabglentrySearch.php)

```
public function search_all($params)
    {
        //~ $query = TabGLEntry::find();
        $query = TabGLEntry::find()->groupBy(['voucher_no'])->all();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'creation' => $this->creation,
            'modified' => $this->modified,
            'voucher_category' => $this->voucher_category,
            'credit' => $this->credit,
            'transaction_date' => $this->transaction_date,
            'clearance_date' => $this->clearance_date,
            'debit' => $this->debit,
            'posting_date' => $this->posting_date,
            'payment_method_id' => $this->payment_method_id,
            'reference_date' => $this->reference_date,
            'is_editable' => $this->is_editable,
            'created_by' => $this->created_by,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
            'is_deleted' => $this->is_deleted,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'entity_name', $this->entity_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'modified_by', $this->modified_by])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'account', $this->account])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fiscal_year', $this->fiscal_year])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'against_voucher', $this->against_voucher])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'against_voucher_type', $this->against_voucher_type])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'is_opening', $this->is_opening])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'against', $this->against])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'voucher_type', $this->voucher_type])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'is_advance', $this->is_advance])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'remarks', $this->remarks])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'cost_center', $this->cost_center])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'reference_no', $this->reference_no])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'voucher_no', $this->voucher_no]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

and now i am getting an error

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Call to a member function andFilterWhere() on a non-object
```

Comment: is there any foreign key in this table? It would be nice if you can add `model` code here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [active record find api](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#find%28%29-detail) find returns a `yii\db\ActiveQueryInterface` instance which can be further customized by calling methods defined in `yii\db\ActiveQueryInterface` before `one()` or `all()` is called to return populated ActiveRecord instances.

So remove the `all()` then you can add filters.